# About memory in C

Tags: c, memory

If memory is word-addressabe and supose a word is 4 byte. How and why 'C programming language' interpret char as 1 byte, and what happens to other 3 bytes?

Comment: Where did you hear that C interprets `char` as 1 byte on machines that are word addressable w/ words being 4 bytes long?

Comment: `word-addressable` does not mean you don't have access to individual bytes it is just that in one shot you will get entire word either for read/write.

Comment: The other 3-bytes can be use by the compiler for other things (like other chars), they might be unused in a `struct` depending on what else is in the struct and the struct packing regime.  All this is *implementation dependant*, not language-dependant.  See also http://www.catb.org/esr/structure-packing/

Comment: Unsure about current C state, however in current C++ compiler would have to generate extra instructions to read/mask/update/write as with architectures which require aligned memory access. Any real world example of such architecture?

Comment: The C standard does not define a "byte" as 8 bits, it defines a "byte" as the smallest unit of addressable storage. So if the smallest unit of addressable storage is 32 bits wide on your machine, a C "byte" (and therefore the `char` type) could be 32 bits wide. It's also possible that the compiler could generate code to make the machine appear to have 8-bit addressable storage.

Answer (score 1):

A byte, by definition, is an addressable unit of data storage large enough to hold a character. This is enshrined in the C language standard. You cannot have unadressable bytes in C. So your C compiler should either define byte to be the same as word, or use software-defined addressing to access individual bytes. Both strategies are valid and both exist in the wild.